# Rails delayed jobs stops on staging

Tags: ruby, linux, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, delayed-job

How to figure out whether delayed job is running or not at background on staging.If it is stop so it should start running by checking some process pid or something .My problem is on staging delayed job stop sometimes and I am not able to figure it out why it happens so can any one tell me what should i possible do to solve this problem.
This is the command i check for checking the status

```
RAILS_ENV=staging ./script/delayed_job status
```

but i need to do something which should check  automatically whether delayed job is running or not .IF not it should start running

Comment: IMO it is not the application's responsibility to monitor and start external processes. I would suggest to use a [monitoring tool](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/server_monitoring) like god or bluepill to monitor that all needed processes are up and running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a shell script file in the root directory and place this code .
Then give permissions to the file

```
ps_out=`ps -ef | grep delayed | grep -v 'grep' | grep -v $0`
result=$(echo $ps_out | grep "$1")
if [[ "$result" != "" ]];then
    echo "Running"
else
    /path-to-your-project/delayed_job start
fi
```

Now add this in crontab

```
crontab -e
```

Answer (score 0):

To monitor if a process is running (and optionally restart it), use something like [god](http://godrb.com/).

If your background jobs are dying, you should increase your log verbosity and maybe use a remote exception notifier like [Airbrake](https://airbrake.io/).

There's dozens of alternatives for both, please do your own research.

To manually check if there's a process running, use

```
> ps aux
```

or top or htop to list the existing processes.